sklearn, gridsearchCV checkpoint
Is there a way to provide checkpointing to GridSearchCV in sklearn? I would love to be able to resume an interrupted search. I'm using the full set of results to plot the evaluation metric scores, hence it would be great to be able to resume with the results of previously examined parameter settings restored into a GridSearchCV instance and continuing to explore the unexamined parameter settings. I'm okay to use another library if needed, doesn't have to be an sklearn-only solution.

Interrupted by you, or by error, or ...?

By me mostly though an unexpected GPU flake error could also be a great thing to be able to recover from. Does it make a difference?
